# Getting an error related to clerk (authentication) after hosting the web application on the vercel

Tags: deployment, middleware, vercel, clerk

I had created a web application and is working fine in the localhost as I expected but when I hosted the same application on vercel and trying to use the application I am getting some log errors which are as follows:

```
-INFO: Clerk: The request to / is being redirected because there is no signed-in user, and the path is not included in `ignoredRoutes` or `publicRoutes`. To prevent this behavior, choose one of:

1. To make the route accessible to both signed in and signed out users, pass `publicRoutes: ["/"]` to authMiddleware
2. To prevent Clerk authentication from running at all, pass `ignoredRoutes: ["/((?!api|trpc))(_next.*|.+\.[\w]+$)", "/"]` to authMiddleware
3. Pass a custom `afterAuth` to authMiddleware, and replace Clerk's default behavior of redirecting unless a route is included in publicRoutes

For additional information about middleware, please visit https://clerk.com/docs/nextjs/middleware
(This log only appears in development mode, or if `debug: true` is passed to authMiddleware)
```

And here is my middleware code:

```
import { authMiddleware } from "@clerk/nextjs";
 
// This example protects all routes including api/trpc routes
// Please edit this to allow other routes to be public as needed.
// See https://clerk.com/docs/references/nextjs/auth-middleware for more information about configuring your Middleware
export default authMiddleware({});
 
export const config = {
      matcher: ['/((?!.+\\.[\\w]+$|_next).*)', '/', '/(api|trpc)(.*)'],
};
```

[The GitHub repo of the project](https://github.com/Sachidananda-17/Connect_Celeb)

Logs:

[image: The error log]

[image: Error]

How can I resolve the error?